# How to update array of objects that includes the array of objects in array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, immutability

```
const example = [
  {
    group: 'Group1',
    subcategories: 
    [
      {
        label: 'Example1',
        content: 'Example1'
      },
      {
        label: 'Example2',
        content: 'Example2'
      },
      {
        label: 'Example3',
        content: 'Example3'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    group: 'Group2',
    subcategories: 
    [
      {
        label: 'Example1',
        content: 'Example1'
      },
      {
        label: 'Example2',
        content: 'Example2'
      },
      {
        label: 'Example3',
        content: 'Example3'
      },
      {
        label: 'Example4',
        content: 'Example4'
      },
      {
        label: 'Example5',
        content: 'Example5'
      },
      {
        label: 'Example6',
        content: 'Example6'
      },
      {
        label: 'Example7',
        content: 'Example7'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    group: 'Group3',
    subcategories: 
    [
      [
        {
          label: 'Example1',
          content: 'Example1'
        },
        {
          label: 'Example2',
          content: 'Example2'
        },
        {
          label: 'Example3',
          content: 'Example3'
        },
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    group: 'Group4',
    subcategories: 
    [
      {
        label: 'Example1',
        content: 'Example1'
      },
      {
        label: 'Example1',
        content: 'Example1'
      },
      {
        label: 'Example1',
        content: 'Example1'
      },
    ]
  },
]

const infogroup = 'Group3';
const infogroupLabel = 'Example2'
const updatedValue = 'updated'

const updated = example.map((group, index) => {
    if (group.group === infogroup) {
        return {
            ...group,
            subcategories: group.subcategories.map((subgroup, index) => {
                if (Array.isArray(subgroup)) {
                    const updatedMetaInfoField = subgroup.map((field, index) => {
                        if (field.label === infogroupLabel) {
                            return { ...field, content: updatedValue };
                        }
                        return field;
                    });
                    return [...updatedMetaInfoField];
                }
                return {
                    ...subgroup,
                    content: subgroup.label === infogroupLabel ? updatedValue : subgroup.content,
                };
            }),
        };
    }
    return group;
});
```

Hi everyone, can someone help me to update this array of objects in an immutable way? The issue is with the Group3 that has Array in Array. Other groups work fine. Also this array of objects can have the same label and content values as you can see in the Group4.

I tried on my own to create the method called "updated" but when I want to update the Group3, it is not working as expected.

Thank you very much for your help.

```
interface Group {
    content: string
    label: string
}

interface GroupInfo {
    group: string
    subcategories: Group[] | Group[][]
}
```

Comment: Could you please update your array as I haven't found any Array in Array.in Group3. There should be `subgroup` property inside `subcategories`.

Comment: `Also this array of objects can have the same label and content values as you can see in the Group4` what do you want to do in that case, do you want to update all labels? Why does group 3 have an array in array for subCategories? If that data came from an api then tell the designer to learn to type entities correctly.

Comment: @HMR I want to update only one content per label.

Comment: @HMR I finally found the solution but I think it will not solve my problem when I have the same label and content...could you help me, please? Thanks

Comment: @DurgeshPal I updated my solution, but I think it will not work if I will have the same label and content values as you can see in the Group4. I want to only update one content per label.

Comment: @MarekKozela The fact that subcategories is either an array or a multi dimensional array for no reason introduces needless complexity, not only in your update code but probably in many other places. I would solve that problem first.

Comment: @HMR I know but still I want to know the solution to my issue with same label and content names. Should I somehow use indexes that provide the map method? Can you, please, help me with this?